# Attempting to dialup gives "Opening port... Error 813: another connection is using...."

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet-connection, pppoe, dial-up

This has driven me to the point of insanity :)

When I wake my computer up and try to dial-up, I get this nice dialog:

> Opening port...
>
> Error 813: You have attempted to establish a second broadband connection while a previous broadband connection already established using the same device or port

And then some more bla bla bla. I've searched the net and I'm not the only one having this problem, but there are no solutions!

So, an option of auto-hangup after 30 minutes of idleness while the sleep is after 60 is very acceptable, but a solution that addresses the problem directly would be super.

Comment: @DearEditor, I was wondering why beginning with greeting the readers and thanking them in the end seemed worthy of elimination in your eyes? Thanks.

Comment: Because it's [unnecessary noise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/131494) that has to be read to get to the actual question.

Comment: Maybe the "bla bla bla" part gives you some suggestions? ;)

Comment: Ok, I get your point (albeit not totally agreeing). But from all the bla bla I don't see any answers. Is it that difficult?

Comment: Is the error a result of the computer being put into suspend while the dialup is active, then being woken with that state remembered, even though the actual dialup connection has gone?

Comment: @Paul: That's exactly the scenario, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we need to do is disconnect the dialup session if the machine goes to sleep.  We can accomplish this with the Task Scheduler, responding to a Sleep event.

Set up the task like this:

1. Input “Task Scheduler” in search box and start the scheduler
2. Click “Create task…”
3. Go to Triggers, create a new trigger, select “On an event”
4. Select Log to “system” , set “Source” to “Kernel-Power” and Event ID to “42”, ok
5. Go to “Actions” and create a new actions, choose "Start a Program"
6. In the program script box put `rasdial /disconnect`

Back in the General tab, give this a name.

So event 42 is posted to the log when the machine is suspended.  This way, when the suspend event is posted it runs `rasdial /disconnect` which will shutdown any dial up connections.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! (sorry for the late reply). I'd have up-voted 10 more times for the wonderfully edited and informative answer :) Cheers